# jquery issue my code will not initiate

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //image time
    //hide the Section
    $("#biocontent,#educontent,#expcontent,#rescontent,#mobcontent,#concontent,#gamcontent").hide();
    //toggle sections   
    $("#bioH").click(function(){
        $("#biocontent").toggle();
    });
    $("#eduH").click(function(){
        $("#educontent").toggle();
    });
    $("#expH").click(function(){
        $("#expcontent").toggle();      
    });
    $("#resH").click(function(){
        $("#rescontent").toggle();      
    });
    $("#mobH").click(function(){
        $("#mobcontent").toggle();      
    });
    $("#conH").click(function(){
        $("#concontent").toggle();      
    });
    $("#gamH").click(function(){
        $("#gamcontent").toggle();      
    });
    setInterval("swapImages()", 2000);
    //swap images for slideshow
    function swapImages(){
        var active = $("#gallery.active");
        var next = ($("#gallery.active").next().length > 0) ? $("#gallery.active").next() : $("#gallery img:first");
        active.removeClass("active");
        next.fadeIn().addClass("active");
    });     
});
```

the question is my last function in the wrong position for it execute i aint so sure were to put another jquery function can some1 look over it :)
i need to know if i have something in the wrong position cheer's

Comment: You're doing it the hard way. Use CLASSES instead. May you please show us your HTML markup? It could help to guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`swapImages` should be in the global (window) scope the way you have written it.

Answer (score 1):

Errors:
 `setInterval("swapImages", 2000);`
and  `function swapImages(){ }); <-- extra ')'`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//image time
//hide the Section
    $("#biocontent,#educontent,#expcontent,#rescontent,#mobcontent,#concontent,#gamcontent").hide();
//toggle sections   
    $("#bioH").click(function(){
            $("#biocontent").toggle();
        });
        $("#eduH").click(function(){
            $("#educontent").toggle();
        });
        $("#expH").click(function(){
            $("#expcontent").toggle();      
        });
        $("#resH").click(function(){
            $("#rescontent").toggle();      
        });
        $("#mobH").click(function(){
            $("#mobcontent").toggle();      
        });
        $("#conH").click(function(){
            $("#concontent").toggle();      
        });
        $("#gamH").click(function(){
            $("#gamcontent").toggle();      
        });

        setInterval(swapImages, 2000);

      //swap images for slideshow
    function swapImages(){
        var active = $("#gallery.active");
        var next = ($("#gallery.active").next().length > 0) ? $("#gallery.active").next() : $("#gallery img:first");
        active.removeClass("active");
        next.fadeIn().addClass("active");

        }     
});
```

Anyway, without seeing your HTML I cannot help further, I just know if you used classes all that code would end up in a few lines of pure awesomeness.

Comment: i am so confused what to do with the code i am having a bimbo moment

Comment: @user1778625 can you explain more? or setup a jsFiddle or a jsBin demo please.

Comment: ok i'am a student i just figured out ur right about the function swapImages(){ i have that in the wrong place i dont know where to put it in my code the rest of my code works fine with out it so my function is either written wrong or in the incorrect place

Comment: @user1778625 that's why I'm asking you again to setup a jsFiddle or jsBin demo for us to play with.

Comment: $(function() {
  setInterval("swapImages()", 2000);
  });
i did this code runs slideshow doesnt work